# python open config file located inside the package

Tags: python, config, setuptools

I'm trying to distribute a python package that has a non python file. The file is located in mypackge/config.yml and I also added it in manifest.in (recursive-include mypackage *.yml). When I run python setup.py install, it is apparently added to the egg but I don't know how to access the file inside the code. `open(os.path.join('mypackage', 'config.yml'))` will stop working as soon as I cd out of the directory where setup.py is...

Is there a way to access the file inside the egg safely, like Java's `getResourceAsStream` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you're looking for is in [`pkg_resources`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) which these days is bundled with `setuptools` and is therefore in general use. Specifically:

```
import pkg_resources
my_data = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "config.yml")
```

Note that this returns bytes. You can even get resources from other packages by replacing `__name__`.

Comment: Can I also get a text stream (I don't want to encode it because that would mean I have to read the whole file and save it decode into a StringIO)?

Comment: You can use `resource_stream` instead of `resource_string` -- gives you a file-like object and will also be in binary (bytes) mode.

Comment: Sorry that is wasn't clear. I already discovered the stream, however, I need a file like object that is in text mode. I don't want to load the complete file into memory in order to convert it into a file in text mode. (I'm also not able to decode it when readline is called because I just give another method a the file).

Comment: Oh, I see now. `io.TextIOWrapper` does that.